# Deduce function template argument for base class

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

In this example I only need to instantiate the template function for the base classes types.

```
struct A{ int i=0; };
struct A1:A{};
struct A2:A{};

struct B{ int i=1; };
struct B1:B{};
struct B2:B{};

template<typename T> uint32_t Checksum ( const T& t )
{
    // make sure we are not instantiating redundant functions
    static_assert(std::is_same<T,A>::value || std::is_same<T,B>::value,"");

    return t.i;
}
template uint32_t Checksum ( const A& t ); //this are actually no ops
template uint32_t Checksum ( const B& t ); //this are actually no ops

int main()
{
    A1 a1;
    A2 a2;
    B1 b1;
    B2 b2;
    Checksum<A>(a1);//ok
    Checksum<A>(a2);//ok
    Checksum<B>(b1);//ok
    Checksum<B>(b2);//ok
    Checksum(b2);  //error

    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to force template type deduction to the base class, ideally without C++17 deduction guides, so that I don't have to specify the type at invocation?

I also tried to explicit instantiate the functions, wondering if they would eventually play in function overload resolution, but the compiler does not pick them. Maybe there is some trick possible with this.

Comment: What should a compiler deduce if `B` had two base classes?

Comment: Why not just have overloads for `uint32_t Checksum ( const A& t )` and `uint32_t Checksum ( const B& t )`?

Comment: @NathanOliver just to avoid repeating code, naturally.

Comment: may I ask for the reason behind this? is it code bloat? I think there are other solutions to your specific problem, otherwise you should stick to NathanOliver's idea of overloading without templates.

Comment: whats wrong with `template<typename T> uint32_t Checksum(const T& t) { return t.i; }` ? It does the correct thing and I dont think you can get it shorter. I wouldnt care about two or three mini instantiations too many but rahter keeping my code concise and readable

Comment: @user463035818, yes, agree when there are just 2 or 3 or 100 types.

Comment: If you add something like `struct B1:B{ using Base = B; };` to all your classes, and `template<typename T> uint32_t Checksum ( const T& t )
{ return CheckSumImpl<typename T::Base>(t); }` then you have a limited number of instantiations of `CheckSumImpl`.

Comment: you agree when there are 2 or 3 or 100 types... in what case you dont agree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

foo.h

```
struct A{ int i=0; };
struct A1:A{};
struct A2:A{};

struct B{ int i=1; };
struct B1:B{};
struct B2:B{};

uint32_t Checksum ( const A& t );
uint32_t Checksum ( const B& t );
```

checkSum.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"

template<typename T> uint32_t ChecksumImpl ( const T& t )
{
    // make sure we are not instantiating redundant functions
    static_assert(std::is_same<T,A>::value || std::is_same<T,B>::value,"");

    return t.i;
}
uint32_t Checksum ( const A& t ) { return ChecksumImpl (t);}
uint32_t Checksum ( const B& t ) { return ChecksumImpl (t);}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"

int main()
{
    A1 a1;
    A2 a2;
    B1 b1;
    B2 b2;
    Checksum(a1);//ok
    Checksum(a2);//ok
    Checksum(b1);//ok
    Checksum(b2);//ok
}
```

Comment: It is what I'm currently using, I was just trying to find if there was a template pure solution for it, guaranteed to be zero-overhead (this possibly is zero-overhead with optimizations, but no guaranteed). But this is likely the only answer possible currently.